# Unable to click/ hover over on href button with Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to click on a button which is located in a sub-menu. Here is the code of the website:

[image: Page and script]

[image: Button I want to click on]

I tried many things like first hover and then click, but I got error and I'm not able to click. Here is what I tried:

```
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Devis')]")
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Suivi devis')]")

hoverover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element1).move_to_element(element2).click().perform()
```

So I want to hover over `DEVIS` and then clique on `Suivi devis`

**Edit**

I don't have to click on `DEVIS`, I just have to hover over with the mouse to open the sub-menus where there is `Suivi devis`

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I'm not able to copy the code and i just don't want to type it because it's long. I prefered screenshot so people can see what i want to do.

Comment: Please take a look at this link : [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/how-to-select-li-element-in-selenium?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @OrhanYazar , why you not able to copy the code? what is the reason?

Comment: I just can't copy, when i click, it just color the selected element